# How to selective show Trace and/or Debug output?

Tags: c#, trace

I want to choose what to show on a textbox, the Debug and/or Trace outputs. How can I achieve that?

At the sample code I only have added the output to the Trace.Listeners, but Debug.Writeline still appears on the textbox. Why?

Expected Result:
Console
Trace

Actual result:
Console
Trace
**Debug**

Sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBoxWriter txtWriter = new TextBoxWriter(this.txbMultiLine);
        Console.SetOut(txtWriter);

        var traceDebugOutput = new TextWriterTraceListener(txtWriter);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(traceDebugOutput);

        Console.WriteLine("Console");
        Trace.WriteLine("Trace");
        Debug.WriteLine("Debug");
    }
}

public class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output = null;

    public TextBoxWriter(TextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, there's no distinction at the listener.  This needs to be done early, when you build your program and use the DEBUG and TRACE conditionals.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't mark your comment as an answer.